# How do I create a file in express and node on my server and then download it to my client. I am using NextJS for my frontend and backend

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

How do I create a file in express and node on my server and then download it to my client. I am using NextJS for my frontend and backend. I am confused on how I would download the file on the front end after the file is created on the root of the server folder. Since I am using React for my frontend whenever I try to visit that filepath it tries to take me to a page instead of the file

Here is what I have in my express route in node

```
  var xls = json2xls(json, {
    fields
  });

  // If there isn't a folder called /temp in the
  // root folder it creates one
  if (!fs.existsSync('./temp')) {
    fs.mkdirSync('./temp');
  }

  const fileName = `temp/${req.user.first_name}${req.body._id + Date.now()}.xlsx`

  // fs.writeFileSync(fileName, xls, 'binary');

  fs.writeFile(fileName, xls, 'binary', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }



    console.log(result, 'this is result')
  });
```

Here is what I have on my frontend

```
  axios.post('api/download',payload)
  .then(res => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = res.data.url;
    link.download
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you make request with GET on api, and.
2. Make request with GET.

Answer (score 0):

Make `temp` directory to be static resources directory:

```
app.use(express.static('temp')); // app is your express instance.
// Maybe you have to correct temp's path
```

Response the post request with file url data

```
  fs.writeFile(fileName, xls, 'binary', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({err});
    }



    console.log(result, 'this is result');

    res.json({url: 'http://localhost:8080/temp/' + fileName}); // res is response object of you router handler.
    // Maybe you have correct the server address
  });
```

On other way, you can send the `xls` binary direct to client, in the client you create a BLOB object from the response, then create download link for the blob object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for frontend for your reference:

In my case, the server-side page cannot transfer blob objects from the server to the client.

So, I have solved this issue by using a component named download-button.tsx, which is used for downloading an Excel file.

component/download-button.tsx

```
async function download() {
  window.location.href = '/api/download';
}

<Button onClick={() => download()}>Download</Button>
```

api/download/route.ts

```
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const requestUrl = `${apiBaseUrl}/path`;
        
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(requestUrl, {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
   },
  });
        
  return new Response(fetchResponse.body, {
   headers: {
   ...fetchResponse.headers,
   'content-disposition': `attachment; filename="filename.xlsx"`,
   },
  });
}
```